# R: How to enable printing to console when using `future::plan(sequential)` when in `browser()`?

Tags: r, future

The future package is great, but when debuging with `future::plan(sequential)`, any `print` doesn't get printed to console.

I think there is an option to enable printing to console.

Hope posting will make it more googlable in the future.

Comment: Thank you for posting this question. I indeed found it from a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Author of future here:) In **future** (>= 1.20.1) [2020-11-03], the official recommended solution is to use:

```r
plan(sequential, split = TRUE)
```

This works with `browser()` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by xiaodai is the best and most robust. I log a separate workaround here that might be useful to some users when editing the arguments to the underlying `future.apply()` call is not convenient (e.g., the call is in a package).

After the `browser()` is called, you can enter `sink()` at the prompt. Output now goes to the terminal. The main caveat to this is that when `future.apply` attempts to close the `sink()` connection, there will be a warning because the connection has already been closed:

```
Warning in base::sink(type = "output", split = FALSE) :
  no sink to remove
```

This is especially annoying if you have the good habit of setting `options(warn = 2)`. To temporarily work around this, you might consider temporarily setting `options(warn = 0)`.